# CKEditor: Center align not working

Tags: ckeditor

In CKEditor, when I select text and set it's alignment to 'center' by clicking button in the toolbar, it appears in the center but when I check its source there is no alignment text.

Comment: Please provide the resulting source code necessary to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Please check if you don't filter this content with [ACF](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_acf.html).
Situation which you describes usually happen, when filter removes attributes for output data.

Answer (score 0):

There should be inline style added in the source like

```html
<p style="text-align: right;">Testing data</p>
```

Can you try to inspect and check some other `css` styles overriding text alignment with (**text-align:left !important.**) applied for your center aligned element.

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).

Comment: Expecting reply from Amit. Its better to give suggestion before asking him to reply  again. Thanks.